# How do I get Ubuntu to laod Radeon drivers after install?

Tags: drivers, radeon

Using the LIVE USB S/W everything is OK. And before with 12.x it was fine. Now I get VGA graphics mode after installing 14.04.  I have modified GRUB to "NOMODESET" which took care of blank screens.

Comment: Have you checked Additional Drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble installing 14.04 on my laptop.  A kind soul gave me these instructions which worked a treat...

1. Start your PC end hit ESC to select from the boot menu and different 
   boot option
2. select USB EFI HDD (or similar)
3. When UBUNTU menu comes up don't boot live disc boot directly 
   installation mode
4. from here on follow the instructions until the installation is finished
5. Ubuntu seems to fail on booting the first time but it's only the 
   X-Server because it can't handle the grafic cards. It will show you that 
   you have to reconfigure your X-server but you don't need to!
6. Switch from error screen to terminal (ctrl+alt+F2) and wait until 
   terminal screen comes up.
7. When terminal is open login with your user credentials
8. Enter: sudo nano /etc/default/grub
9. Nano editor will open the Grub configuration. Enter there 'nomodeset' 
   in line  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" before 'quiet 
   splash'. (please se grub.txt attached)
10. enter 'ctrl+O' (see menu at the bottom of nano) to save and 'ctrl+X' 
    to exit
11. reconfigure Grub with command 'sudo update-grub'
12. reboot your PC and it should start in X mode
13. Download latest 64bit catalyst from amd site (latest stable is 14.4 )
14. change authorization in terminal for this file by entering 'sudo 
    chmod 777 amd-catalyst-14-4-linux-x86-x86-64.zip'
15. unzip file and run from terminal by entering 'sudo 
    ./amd-driver-installer-14.10.1006-x86.x86_64.run' (you must be in the 
    same folder!!!!)
16. you can decide if you want to do a custom installation or default. I 
    recommend to use the default way!
17. when installation is finished  go to terminal again and remove the 
    'nomodeset' from grub by entering 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub' edit it 
    and close it again. Run 'sudo update-grub'.

Good luck!